# `join` method importing `other` dataframe values as `NaN`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

*Editing this to reflect addition work:*

**Situation**

I have 2 pandas dataframes of Twitter search tweets API data in which I have a common data key, `author_id`.

I'm using the `join` method.

Code is:

`dfTW08 = dfTW07.join(dfTW04uf, on='author_id', how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='4')`

**Results**

When I run that, everything comes out as expected, except that all the `other` dataframe (`dfTW04uf`) values come in as `NaN`. Including the values for the `other` dataframe's `author_id` column.

**Assessment**

I'm not getting any error messages, but have to think it's something about the datatypes. The `other` dataframe is a mix of int64, object, bool, and datetime datatypes. So it seems odd they'd all be unrecognized.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure out the `NaN` issue using `join`, but was able to `merge` the databases with this:

`callingdf.merge(otherdf, on='author_id', how='left', indicator=True)`

Then did `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates` to get the final list I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` instead of `join` since `merge` had everything `join` does but with more "power". (anything you can do with `join` you can do with `merge`)

I am assuming the `NaN` is coming up since the results aren't being discarded when you asked the first `join` to use on author ID and then include suffixes fo x an y. When you `left join` with `merge` you are discarding the non matches without any x and y suffixes.